# Is there a tool to generate Spring application context dependency diagram/graph?

Tags: spring

Is there a tool to generate diagram/graph of Spring application context?

The tool should take into consideration also annotation driven configuration (like @Autowired).

The tool may generate the dependency diagram by 'dumping' BeanDefinitions in runtime.
I.e. I don't require the tool to make static code analysis.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The Spring IDE + Eclipse or the Spring Source Tool Suite can generate simple graphs of your dependencies.

To do that open the view called "Spring Explorer" and choose your project. Then click right mouse -> Properties and combine some/all of your context files into a "Config Set". After saving you can right click on it in the Spring Explorer and choose "Open dependency graph".

The graph is static and quite untidy, but this might help.

Comment: I can't find the Spring Explorer view in 2021 STS4, nor any reference to Config Sets.  Has this feature been dropped?

Comment: Not in Spring Tool Suite 4 (Version: 4.10.0.RELEASE, Build Id: 202103111225) either, https://stackoverflow.com/a/54950361/325224

Answer (score 16):

IntelliJ IDEA's Ultimate Edition can generate a Spring dependency graph.  Basically, right click on the file name and select `Diagrams -> Show Diagram`.  This [web page](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/spring-dependencies-diagram.html) provides the details.

Comment: @oshaiken - Thanks for the comment.  I've added your info to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Another tool you may want to look into: https://github.com/aigor/spring-beans-visualized

It purely works on a running `ApplicationContext` and does not do a static analysis. It does need `Spring-Boot` though to work.