# How to get Spring Explorer view in Eclipse 2018-12 with Spring Tool Suite 4 installed?

Tags: spring, eclipse, spring-tool-suite

In the past, I've directly installed the Spring Tool Suite, and I remember seeing the graphical "Spring Explorer" view, that graphically rendered my Spring Bean references.

For a while now, I've been installing the stock Eclipse distro, and then installing STS from the marketplace.

I'm now using Eclipse 2018-12, with the latest STS from the marketplace, and now I realize that I don't have an option to display this "Spring Explorer" view.

How can I graphically display Spring bean references in Eclipse 2018-12 with the latest STS installed?

Answer (score 1):

There is **no *Spring Explorer*** view **in** Spring Tools 4 (**STS4**).

See the closed [STS4 issue #23 - *No more Spring Perspective neither Spring Explorer?*](https://github.com/spring-projects/sts4/issues/23), [comment by project lead Martin Lippert](https://github.com/spring-projects/sts4/issues/23#issuecomment-350645260):

> The STS4 distribution takes a fresh start with many things and
>   therefore doesn't include the Spring perspective and the Spring
>   explorer anymore.
>
> The Spring Explorer will be replaced with the new "go to symbol"
>   infrastructure that provides a much faster and more lightweight way to
>   get an overview of your Spring elements in your project. And since the
>   Spring Explorer was the main difference between the Java and the
>   Spring perspective, we decided to not configure a specialized Spring
>   perspective anymore. In addition to that the "go to symbol"
>   infrastructure is available independent of the chosen perspective.
>
> [...]

[The discussion here was moved to the issue mentioned above (with replies from the project lead Martin Lippert).](https://github.com/spring-projects/sts4/issues/23#issuecomment-469039959)

Comment: And so does anyone know anything about this "goto-symbol" command that is supposed to take the place of all of this?  This does nothing for me, and I can't find any documentation for it.

Comment: @DavidM.Karr See https://github.com/spring-projects/sts4/wiki/Navigation

Comment: @DavidM.Karr STS4 is technically and conceptually very different from STS3 (as an interim solution you can install both together). There are some good videos that explain the idea of STS4, e. g. [this one I enjoyed watching](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1CRgi1Yk7S0).

Comment: I'm watching the video, but this "goto-symbol" thing just does nothing. There's nothing in the log when I execute it, it just does nothing.

Comment: Ok, now making progress. I first had to check "Java Source File" for "Spring Boot Language Server" in the "Language Servers" section. It also didn't occur to me initially that I had to have my spring boot app running for Ctrl+6 to do anything.  I'm now at the point where hovering on "@Autowired" just gives me the javadoc for @Autowired instead of the Spring Boot data.

Comment: please note that the go to symbol feature is something totally different than the live hover hints from running spring boot apps. Regarding your issue with the go-to-symbol infrastructure, I replied to your question in the GitHub issue here: https://github.com/spring-projects/sts4/issues/23#issuecomment-469039959 - also please feel free to file an issue about the problems you seem to have with the live hover hints for annotations and we can proceed from there.